# thread-safe expiring multi-valued map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I am looking for an already existing Java implementation of a thread-safe, multi-valued (one key -> multiple values) map which allows setting separate time-based expiration for each value. The expiration policy is simple TTL (time to live) after CREATE.

I looked at the following available implementations:

- [Guava LoadingCache](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap):  but it supports only global expiration for the cache
- [ExpiringMap](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap): it supports individual entry expiration but it does not support multiple values for a key with each having its own TTL

I am looking at something like this:

```
public interface ExpiringMultiValuedCache<K, V> {
    List<V> get(K key);
    void set(K key, V value, long ttl, TimeUnit timeUnit);
    void remove(V value);
}
```

The requirement is that, one thread will continuously add and remove entries into the map and there will be multiple threads reading the values (calling `get()`)

Comment: Have a look at ehcache or a memcached java client. Both would support your use case

Comment: @jontro I believe memcached java client would still be backed by a memcached cluster? I am looking for an in-memory solution.

Comment: Well have a look at ehcache then ;)